# DummyNet error NDIS drivers install on Windows 7 x64

Tags: networking, driver, windows-7-x64, ndis, ipfw

I've download the current version of [DummyNet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/) and according to [readme](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/README) I'm following these steps:

> Windows: INSTALL THE NDIS DRIVER
>
> - open the configuration panel for the network card in use
>       (right click on the icon on the SYSTRAY, or go to
>       Control Panel -> Network and select one card)
> - click on Properties->Install->Service->Add
> - click on 'Driver Disk' and select 'netipfw.inf' in this folder
> - select 'ipfw+dummynet' which is the only service you should see
> - click accept on the warnings for the installation of an unknown
>       driver (roughly twice per existing network card)

But when I select 'netipfw.inf' and click OK the system return an error (unable to find any drivers for this device).

Note that I've previously disabled the check control for digital signature typing on Start->Exec the following command:

```
bcdedit /set nointegritychecks ON
```

and reeboting the system.

I need to be able to solve this issue because when I try to execute some dummynet command the system returns:

```
my_socket failed 2, cannot talk to kernel module
ipfw: socket
```

My network card is a NVIDIA nForce integrated on my mother board Asus Striker II.

Have you any idea to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: could you solve your problem with the digital sign?? I have the same one and dont know what to do! thansk

Comment: Sorry but today I don't have resolved my problem yet. For my test I use `ipfw` in Mac OS. Good luck.

Comment: The 64-bit driver is compiled only for amd. If you have an 64-bit Intel CPU, you cannot install the driver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to get this working using Windows 7 x64.

Download [**DummyNet**](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet).

Move the files from `ipfw3-2012\binary64` to `ipfw3-2012\binary`, choose
<kbd>Move and Replace</kbd>

Install the driver using instruction in `ipfw3-2012\binary\README.txt`.

Note I had to reboot with `Disable Driver Signature Enforcement` as detailed
[**here**](http://sabrent.com/support/knowledgebase.php?article=14) before I could install the driver. Should look like this

[image: ipfw]

Comment: Did not work for me, managed to install it once after reboot etc. normal internet connection stopped working. Switching to another program.

Comment: In my case It is working fine in windows-7 x64. When I try to install it in windows-10 machine getting same error "my_socket failed 2, cannot talk to kernel module ipfw: socket". Seems ipfw not supporting in windows-10. Could you help me how to fix.

Answer (score 2):

Dummynet is a 32bit NDIS driver, if you look through the source at: http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet you can see that the `ipfw` folder only has exports from `ws2_32.dll`

You would need to port the driver to x64 to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command prompt as Administrator. For example, open the start menu, find command prompt, right click it and hit "run as administrator" this is likely your issue. It is similar to trying to run this on MacOS and not using the "sudo" command. If this doesn't solve your problem I would be concerned that it was because you are on 64bit and I don't believe Dummynet is compatible on that architecture yet.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I previously tried in this way but with no results. I finally used Mac OS.

Comment: No problem. I noticed you moved to a mac but I posted to help other users that might be searching as well.

Comment: Hello @Michael ! Do you have any idea why ipfw failed to install in windows-10 x64. As ipfw3 for windows architecture built for x64 machine.