# Dummynet Installation Failure : my_socket failed 2, cannot talk to kernel module (Windows 7 X64)

Tags: windows, 64-bit, ipfw

I am trying to install IPFW on a 64 bit version of Windows 7 using the package provided [here](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/)

I am able to successfully add the `ipfw+dummynet` service to my network adapter using the instructions supplied in [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994584/dummynet-error-ndis-drivers-install-on-windows-7-x64/12719202#12719202)

However, while executing the `ipfw.exe` provided in the package, I face the following error :

> my_socket failed 2, cannot talk to kernel module

Need assistance in getting past this error so that ipfw can be run successfully from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method explained [here](http://thephuck.com/end-user-computing/how-to-disable-driver-signing-requirement-in-windows-8/) worked for me.

I also succeed to install the driver with the 2nd methode but I had to sign the driver myself first, as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487328.aspx). To bypass the error related to the catalog file, add the following line after the version tag on the INF file :

```
CatalogFile.NTAMD64 = wipfwamd64.cat
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect ! The first method worked for me as well.
For the second method, although the driver runs in test mode, i still needed to install it after disabling driver signature as described in the first method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same message error as you with my windows server 2012 based on a 64 bit architecture.

I checked the code, the error value is returned from the windows function [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

```
2 (0x2) : ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

This error occurs when the windows function [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is called on I/O device "Ipfw".

```
If the specified file or device does not exist, the function fails and the last-error code is set to ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (2).
```

To make it quick I think the "Ipfw" service is missing, it shows as right installed but its not.

Comment: i agree. Disabling and Re-Enabling the adapter causes an error which i think is indicative of the service not being correctly installed.